# MySQLi prepared statements with a full stop (.)?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to search a table full of domain names in the format:

```
10minutemail.com
```

My problem is I don't know how to escape the fullstop in my SELECT statement so that I actually get a response.

```
$_POST['email'] = strtolower($_POST['email']);

$maildomain = explode('@', $_POST['email']);

$domain = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM `blacklist` WHERE Domain = ?');
$domain->bind_param('s',$maildomain[1]);
$domain->execute();
$domain->store_result();

echo $domain->num_rows;
```

Returns "0" regardless of whether `$maildomain[1]` is actually contained in the table.

phpMyAdmin does the same thing [phpMyAdmin Results Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyRPp.png)

Comment: phpMyAdmin escapes everything fine, so the meaning of your screenshot is that string is not found. Note though that the string you have here (10minutemail.com) and the one in your picture (0-mail.com) are different. Can you do a general browse in phpMyAdmin to show that the latter does in fact exist in there? It's worth getting the database working first, and then fixing the PHP.

Comment: @MrMayo Did you print & checked the value of $maildomain[1] before executing with prepared statement?

Comment: @halfer sure, I did two different examples just to show it happened on everything. Here shows the database with a bunch of domains: http://puu.sh/617iP.png I think it is unlikely but could there be some random invisible character at the end of the domain names which are changing its value?

Comment: @JensonMJohn yes, it is definitely what is is meant to be.

Comment: @MrMayo Just try trim($maildomain[1]) before sending.

Comment: OK, in phpMyAdmin try `SELECT FROM blacklist WHERE domain LIKE '%10minutemail%'` and see if that gets you anything. If it does, add the dot in, and if that works, add the "com" in too. That would point to preceding or trailing space/CRs, good idea.

Comment: @JensonMJohn Unfortunately no change

Comment: @MrMayo Is it possible to share that table sql dump if it's not too heavy?

Comment: @halfer HAH! I believe you have got it. `SELECT * FROM  blacklist WHERE  Domain LIKE  "10minutemail.com%"` works, but if I remove that final "%" then I get nothing! So there is some random invisible junk at the end of the domain names.. Fun fun!

Comment: Great stuff. You could do an `UPDATE` that trims them all in phpMyAdmin, and then ensure any new ones you put in the database are properly trimmed. That will allow the use of the faster comparison, rather than the slow `LIKE`.

Comment: Will do. Thank you for the help. Thanks for the help as well @JensonMJohn.

Comment: Please also specify whats in your $_POST['email']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was an invisible character at the end of the domain names in the table. After trimming the domain names to remove any junk either side of it the query worked as it should have.